Firebird Server Installed but no Firebird Service
I downloaded Firebird 2.1.7 tar file. Installed with install.sh. I can connect to the db at /opt/firebird/bin/isql, but how do I set it up as a service? There is no Firebird service and no instruction on how to achieve this. Is there a repository that will allow to apt install previous Firebird versions?
What I really need is the gbak tool. I'm trying to access a database in Firebird 3.0 with ODS 11.2 (which Firebird 3.0 does not support). I understand I need to backup the database in Firebird 2.1 and restore with 3.0 gbak tool.

By "can connect to the db" it looks like you installed a Classic Server. "Service" in this case is configured in (x)inetd.

Using Firebird 2.1 to try to access an ODS 11.2 database should fail, because ODS 11.2 is the ODS introduced with Firebird 2.5, and only supported by Firebird 2.5. Also, if you can connect with ISQL, then you should also be able to backup without having the service running. Just use file paths without a hostname included.

In any case, this is not really a programming question. You may want to consider asking on firebird-support instead.

I ended up downloading the v2.5  windows executable, created the backup there and restored it in my linux distro. But i guess that still does not answer the question.

Your question is to maintainers of repositories of your distro. Firebird Project doesn't release packages.

@user13964273 That is not correct. The download page the OP links contains multiple binary packages for Linux, and the project still releases (some of) those.

As a workaround, you could try and use the Firebird 2.5.9 docker image from https://hub.docker.com/r/jacobalberty/firebird (use v2.5.9-sc, iirc there was a problem with v2.5.9-ss).

@MarkRotteveel "Binaries" != "packages" in Linux world. What you can download from firebirdsql.org are just generic binaries that may not fit to a specific distro rules (if work at all).
